# Find a right angled triangle

Tags: coordinate-transformation

If I am given 10 points in the coordinate system in the for `(x,y)`; where `x` is the x-coordinate and `y` is the y-coordinate.

Is there a way that I can predict if there is a right angled triangle possible with these vertices? (Not by taking 3 vertices at a time and applying Pythagoras and checking? Is there a way?)

Thanks for any help in advance.. :)

Comment: Why would anybody vote to close this interesting question?

Comment: I am confused - are you searching for a mathematical theorem to determine the presence of right triangles or are you wondering if Mathematica can identify right triangles in a set of points?  If the former, this is not the right forum; if the latter, then why must the answer not involve the Pythagorean theorem?

Comment: @bobthechemist And ... you can't do it without "taking three points at a time" b/c you need to consider all segments ...

Comment: @eldo Utter absence of an example? That would be my guess (for votes to close, that is).

Comment: working on this? http://www.codechef.com/OCT14/problems/CHEFSQUA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made 10 points randomly and selected points as vertex of right-angled triangle using `VectorAngle`.

```
pts = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {10, 2}]
```

> `{{2, 6}, {7, 9}, {8, 7}, {4, 8}, {1, 1}, {7, 3}, {9, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 
>     4}, {7, 3}}`

```
vts = Permutations[pts, {3}];
rst = Select[vts, VectorAngle @@ Differences[#1] == \[Pi]/2 &];
trig = Union[rst, SameTest -> (Sort[#1] == Sort[#2] &)]
```

> `{{{1, 1}, {4, 4}, {2, 6}}, {{2, 6}, {8, 7}, {9, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {4, 
>      4}, {7, 3}}, {{4, 4}, {2, 6}, {4, 8}}, {{4, 8}, {8, 7}, {7, 
>      3}}, {{7, 9}, {4, 4}, {9, 1}}}`

I verified with drawing the triangles like this.

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Darker@Orange], 
  Opacity[.5], {ColorData["Atoms", "ColorList"][[1 ;; Length[trig]]], 
    Polygon[Append[#, First[#]]] & /@ trig} // Transpose, Opacity[1], 
  PointSize[Medium], Red, Point@pts}, Axes -> True]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: +1 IMO you could even improve your nice answer by just telling us `True` (at least one right-angled) or `False` :)

Comment: I just wondered how can there be so many right angled triangles if you only "made 10 points randomly", then I realized that your points are all on the Interger lattices.

Comment: Maybe `rst = Select[vts, Dot @@ Differences[#] == 0 &];` is a cheaper approach than VectorAngle ?

Comment: @Harry You right thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using test case of Juhno Lee (noting repeated point {7,3}):

```
test = {{2, 6}, {7, 9}, {8, 7}, {4, 8}, {1, 1}, {7, 3}, {9, 1}, {3, 
   1}, {4, 4}, {7, 3}}
```

Function to select points:

```
fun[tp_] := Module[{sb},
  If[Length[Union@tp] < 3, 1,
   sb = Partition[tp,2,1,1];
   #1.#2 & @@Flatten[Differences /@Most@SortBy[sb, N[EuclideanDistance @@ #] &], 1]]]
```

Applying:

```
sub = Subsets[test, {3}];
trn = Union[Sort /@ Pick[sub, fun /@ sub, 0]]
```

Visualizing:

```
anim = Show[
     ListPlot[test, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red],
      Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Blue, Opacity[0.5], Polygon[#]}], 
     PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> Table[{0, 9}, {2}]] & /@ trn;
```

Animated gif for frames:

[image]

**UPDATE**
In response to eldo's comment:

```
g[pts_] := 
 With[{s = Subsets[pts, {3}]}, Union[Sort /@ Pick[s, fun /@ s, 0]]]
```

For sample of 100 random integer point sets of size 10:

```
cnt = RandomInteger[9, {100, 10, 2}];
anim2 = MapThread[
  Column[{Show[
      ListPlot[#1, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
      Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Blue, Opacity[0.5], Polygon[##2]}], 
      PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
      PlotRange -> Table[{0, 9}, {2}]], Length@#2}, 
    Alignment -> Center] &, {cnt, (g /@ cnt)}];
```

The number of right triangle is displayed below graphic:

[image]

The mean number of right triangles found was 10.39 median 10, range: 1 to 21. This histogram is shown below:

[image]

In three simulations of sample size 10000, no right triangles occurred 12,10 and 11->Probability at least 1 right triangle from 10 points with integer valued points:$\approx 0.9990$.

Here are 11 configurations without right triangle from one 10000 simulation:

[image]

Comment: Rephrasing my comment to Junho Lee's answer: How many right-angled triangles are there? Could you provide an `Integer` between `0` and `1000` ? +1 anyway :)

Comment: @eldo 6 for  original test case, see update